# how to view (see) the stored values in the database in android without programatically

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-emulator

Can somebody help me to see the values that are stored in a database non-programatically? Using file explorer and command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

1. using command line
   a) enter adb shell
   b) cd to your app directory, database file will under databases folder
   c) $sqlite3 yourdb_name
   d) ## now you should enter command mode
   e) select * from your_tablename;
2. using ddms
   a) using DDMS's file explorer
   b) find the database file
   c) copy databases to ypur PC
   d) use any sqlite tool to read it

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

use [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool **sqlite3(.exe)** of the SQLite library.

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Answer (score 0):

download sqlite browser and browse your data and you can see its tables and its data [use this blog to learn more.](http://bhutiyagirish.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/browse-android-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to get the Database from the DDMS in eclipse?

I was searching in the data folder for the application and I didn't find it there.